# touchpad horizontal scrolling in emacs

Tags: emacs, scroll, mouse

app on Mac OS X on a MacBook.  Most applications on the computer allow me to scroll both vertically and horizontally with a two-finger drag on the trackpad.  I would like to use this ability to position the cursor in emacs.

Adding the following lines to .emacs allows me to move the cursor vertically:

```
(global-set-key [wheel-up] 'previous-line)
(global-set-key [wheel-down] 'next-line)
```

I don't know of an equivalent setting for wheel-left or wheel-right.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I am having the same problem. How can I make it to scroll more than 1 line?

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your .emacs-file:

```
;; Turn on horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-6>") 'scroll-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-7>") 'scroll-left)
```

When you first use it, emacs will ask you if you want to activate the restricted command scroll-left. That's just because some users find it confusing at first.

Comment: How to achieve same behavior but for emacs window under the mouse cursor, not just current buffer (like vertical scrolling doing)?

Comment: **UPD** oh, I see from `(defun mwheel-scroll` – `(buffer (window-buffer curwin))`.

Answer (score 5):

this slightly simpler version works for me:

```
(global-set-key [wheel-right] 'scroll-left)
(global-set-key [wheel-left] 'scroll-right)
```

or for osx reversed scroll directions:

```
(global-set-key [wheel-right] 'scroll-left)
(global-set-key [wheel-left] 'scroll-right)
```

Comment: what's the difference between the two versions?

Answer (score 3):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-7>")
  (lambda () (interactive) (message "WHEEEEEL")))
```

That worked for me. Try `C-h c` and then scroll the mouse the way you intend to to see what event is triggered. It will tell you in the echo area.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with the MagicTrackpad, C-h c also doesn't show anything for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: For me it doesn't work (usual trackpad). Why can be a reason?

Answer (score 2):

In version 26.2 I can set these variables from the `mouse` customize group:

```
'(mouse-wheel-flip-direction t) ;; correct left-right scroll direction for OS X
'(mouse-wheel-tilt-scroll t)    ;; enable left-right scroll from trackpad
```

Comment: That worked very well for me with Emacs 28.0.50 and xterm-mouse-mode, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In emacs 25.1 check out the `*Messages*` buffer when you swipe left and right on the trackpad. By the looks of it the key bindings are `wheel-right` and `wheel-left` with double and triple variants.

For example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<triple-wheel-right>")
  (lambda () (interactive) (message "wheeling right")))

(global-set-key (kbd "<triple-wheel-left>")
  (lambda () (interactive) (message "wheeling left")))
```

For me these values are **not** reversed in macOS